# Xades4j produces an invalid signature with signSigningCertificate set to true and DataObjectFormatProperty

Tags: xades4j

I have my basic signature options class:

```
public class MyDefaultBasicSignatureOptionsProvider implements BasicSignatureOptionsProvider {
    (...)
    @Override
    public boolean signSigningCertificate() {
        return true;
    }   
}
```

And my signing code is:

```
    String fileName = "documentIn.xml";
    DataObjectDesc obj1 = new DataObjectReference(fileName )
                                    .withDataObjectFormat(new DataObjectFormatProperty("mineType", "encoding"));

    SignedDataObjects objs = new SignedDataObjects( obj1 ).withBaseUri( "file:///"+path );

    Document doc = db.newDocument();

    signer.sign( objs, doc);
```

The problem is:

The output signature contains the following:

```
            <xades:SignedDataObjectProperties>
                <xades:DataObjectFormat ObjectReference="#">
                    <xades:MimeType>mineType</xades:MimeType>
                    <xades:Encoding>encoding</xades:Encoding>
                </xades:DataObjectFormat>
            </xades:SignedDataObjectProperties>
```

And of course, the ObjectReference="#" is not correct. Checking this signature with xades4j gives an error.

If I remove the data object format or the signSigningCertificate to return false it works, but with both options I get this error.

Can someone confirm this? How can I solve this?

Comment: I'll try to reproduce the issue soon and get back to you.

Comment: I've reproduced the problem. It happens not only on detached signatures (as in your case) but also on the other signature types. I'll see what I can do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a bug on the lib; kudos for finding/reporting it. The problem is on the following lines, executed when processing the signed data objects:

```
Reference ref = xmlSignature.getSignedInfo().item(referenceMappings.size());
referenceMappings.put(dataObjDesc, ref);
```

When the signing certificate is signed the `Reference` over `KeyInfo` is added prior to processing the signed data objects. This means that when accessing `.item(referenceMappings.size())` the returned reference is not the one just added but the previous one, resulting in a wrong mapping. In your cases, since you only have a singed data object, the previous reference is always the `KeyInfo` reference, which doesn't have an ID. This results on the described output (`ObjectReference="#"`).

This bug affected all the properties that apply to individual data objects, namely `DataObjectFormat`, `CommitmentType` and `IndividualDataObjectsTimeStamp`.

The bug has been corrected and the fix is available at the project's source code. In addition, a new version of the lib will be published today.

Comment: Thanks. I will have a look. I may have more stuff to report, but let me re-test all things and see what make sense.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and started to investigate the issue.

The code which is setting the id seems to be in class **xades4j.production.DataGenDataObjFormat** method **generatePropertyData**:

```
public PropertyDataObject generatePropertyData(...) {
    DataObjectDesc targetDataObjInfo = prop.getTargetDataObjects().iterator().next();

    // EMPTY OBJECT REFERENCE IS CREATED HERE: //     
    String objRef = '#' + ctx.getReferencesMappings().get(targetDataObjInfo).getId();
    Object obj = ctx.getReferencesMappings();

    ....

    return dataObjFormatData;
}
```

Debugging showed, that the correct object is referenced. But as the result is only '#' in the output file, it seems that the IDs are not yet initialized to a value.

I will continue to investigate, but would appreciate further insights.

**UPDATE**
I have found a dirty workaround to set the reference manually. I changed the code in generatePropertyData to set the objRef manually and used the fact that the reference to the root document ends with ref0:

```
  Collection<Reference> rc = ctx.getReferencesMappings().values();
    for (Reference rc1 : rc) {
        DeferredDocumentImpl obj = (DeferredDocumentImpl)rc1.getDocument();
        Enumeration e = obj.getIdentifiers();
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
            String nl = e.nextElement().toString();
            if (nl.endsWith("ref0")) {
                objRef = "#"+nl;
            }
        }    
    }
```

**Hopefully someone comes up with a real solution soon.**